# Export on custom JS class causes error on in test using babel-jest

Tags: unit-testing, vue.js, jestjs, babeljs, babel-jest

In my Vue app test file I'm pulling in `import Users from '@/models/user';`

I've cleared the cache before running the test but it doesn't seem to help..

In the `src/models/user.js` file I have:

```
export default class Users {

}
```

When I run the test I get the error:

```
({"Object.<anonymous>":function(module,exports,require,__dirname,__filename,global,jest){export default function _classCallCheck(instance, Constructor) {
                                                                                         ^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token export



  at ScriptTransformer._transformAndBuildScript (node_modules/jest-runtime/build/script_transformer.js:403:17)
  at Object.<anonymous> (src/models/user.js:10:47)
```

`jest.config.js` is as follows:

```
module.exports = {
  moduleFileExtensions: [
    'js',
    'jsx',
    'json',
    'vue'
  ],
  transform: {
    '^.+\\.vue$': 'vue-jest',
    '.+\\.(css|styl|less|sass|scss|svg|png|jpg|ttf|woff|woff2)$': 'jest-transform-stub',
    '^.+\\.jsx?$': 'babel-jest'
  },
  moduleNameMapper: {
    '^@/(.*)$': '<rootDir>/src/$1'
  },
  snapshotSerializers: [
    'jest-serializer-vue'
  ],
  testMatch: [
    '**/tests/unit/**/*.spec.(js|jsx|ts|tsx)|**/__tests__/*.(js|jsx|ts|tsx)'
  ],
  testURL: 'http://localhost/'
}
```

and my `babel.config.js` is:

```
module.exports = {
  presets: [
    '@vue/app',
    '@babel/preset-env'
  ]
}
```

Comment: I think this my be a compiling error. When I import the same class in a view it works fine. If I then run the tests, all of the tests error out. Weird as Vue is importing/exporting a ton of other classes too..

Comment: On top of that.. If I just export a static JSON object - no error! Am I exporting classes incorrectly?

Comment: **Update:** Converted project to run on Mocha + Chai test runner instead